# How to get the all the files(their file paths) in a folder from a web directory?

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm trying to make a UWP file browser app that show all the files from http://192.168.201.254/media/, to do that I need to get all the file paths under http://192.168.201.254/media/, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clients can only request known file URLs via HTTP.

The server can be configured to spit out an HTML file list as default page for the directory and you can process that on the client side.